# How may i sort string data(time 12 hr format) in ascending order?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column named as class_time having string format in which data is stored as:

```
0730PM:0600PM:0800PM
```

How can I fetch this column data as ascending time?

```
0600PM:0730PM:0800PM
```

Comment: Do you have a column with three rows each containing a single time or do you have a column with one row containing a delimited string which contains three times?

Comment: i have a single column containing three times separated by colon as i mentioned in question

Comment: Don't store data like that. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: If only Oracle had a `time` data type...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`

Comment: @MT0: close, but not the same. But probably better than using a varchar

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, '0730PM:0600PM:0800PM' from dual union all
  3     select 2, '0400PM:0300AM:0200AM' from dual union all
  4     select 3, '1130PM:1200AM:1230AM' from dual union all
  5     select 4, '1200AM:0100AM:0200AM' from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    (select id,
  9            regexp_substr(col, '[^:]+', 1, column_value) val
 10     from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                                              connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ':') + 1
 12                                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 13    )
 14  select id,
 15    listagg(val, ':') within group (order by to_date(val, 'hhmiam')) result
 16  from temp
 17  group by id;

        ID RESULT
---------- ------------------------------
         1 0600PM:0730PM:0800PM
         2 0200AM:0300AM:0400PM
         3 1200AM:1230AM:1130PM
         4 1200AM:0100AM:0200AM

SQL>
```

Comment: appreciated but sir in case of both present AM and PM so order will as
1130PM:1200AM:1230AM, please have a look.

Comment: Slight change in ORDER BY; added `substr(val, -2)`.

Comment: That's what happens when you use AM/PM. We (in Croatia) don't, we have 24 hours in a day :) Another ORDER BY modification, hopefully, fixes that. Thank you, @MT0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive sub-query and simple string functions to split the string into times and then use `LISTAGG` to re-concatenate them ordering by the ascending times.

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( times ) AS
SELECT '0730PM:0600PM:0800PM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0730PM:0730AM:0600PM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0730PM:0730AM:0600PM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT ( SELECT LISTAGG(
                  TO_CHAR( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'HH12MIAM' ),
                  ':'
                ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() )
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24 ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH bounds ( rid, times, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT ROWID,
         times,
         1,
         INSTR( times, ':', 1 )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT rid,
         times,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR( times, ':', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
),
time_strings ( rid, value ) AS (
  SELECT rid,
         CASE end_pos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR( times, start_pos )
         ELSE SUBSTR( times, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
         END
  FROM   bounds
)
SELECT LISTAGG( value, ':' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY TO_DATE( value, 'HH12MIAM' ) )
         AS times
FROM   time_strings
GROUP BY rid;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | TIMES                                                                                                                                                                   |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 0600PM:0730PM:0800PM                                                                                                                                                    |
> | 0730AM:0600PM:0730PM                                                                                                                                                    |
> | 0730AM:0600PM:0730PM                                                                                                                                                    |
> | 1200AM:0100AM:0200AM:0300AM:0400AM:0500AM:0600AM:0700AM:0800AM:0900AM:1000AM:1100AM:1200PM:0100PM:0200PM:0300PM:0400PM:0500PM:0600PM:0700PM:0800PM:0900PM:1000PM:1100PM |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=47fd1cbe5f11e7df3e697291d5a8428b)*

Comment: appreciated but sir in case of both present AM and PM so order will as 1130PM:1200AM:1230AM, please have a look

Comment: @AbdulRaheem "How can I fetch this column data as ascending time?" This returns them in ascending time `AM` first then `PM` which you can see if you please have a look at the sample output from the query.